How to get scope defined scopes in WSO2 DevPortal?
I am trying to get OAuth access token for one of the published APIs. I have defined a local scope "XYZ_Scope" for the API resource. When I go the DevPortal I am able to generate scope defined scope using the UI but no using the curl command.
Here is how the curl command looks like:
curl --location 'https://{your-ip-address}:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret)' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=username' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password'

Here is how the response look:
{
    "access_token": "*token*",
    "scope": "default",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}

I am not able to access the published API using the access token. Here is the issue I am facing:
{
    "code": "900910",
    "message": "The access token does not allow you to access the requested resource",
    "description": "User is NOT authorized to access the Resource: /{device-name}/{resource-name}. Scope validation failed."
}

Is there a possibility that I can add my local scope to the curl command to get the access token?
Thank you for answering.

In the token call, you have to specify the necessary scope for your token as below.
curl --location 'https://{your-ip-address}:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret)' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=username' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=XYZ_Scope'

If you need to request a token with several scopes, then you have to specify them in a space-separated manner as below.
curl --location 'https://{your-ip-address}:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret)' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=username' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=ABC_scope XYZ_Scope'

